# Sinon stub class instance assigned in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

I have a class which has a constructor that calls an imported module's constructor

```
...

constructor(ctx: Context) {
  this.service = new Service(ctx)
}
```

I want to test this class, but want to stub the service as I only want to test a given method on this class. So, in my test I have created a stub instance like so

```
...

const serviceStub = sinon.createStubInstance(Service)
const controller = new Controller(ctx)
serviceStub.create.resolves(null)
```

However, when I run the test, I get the following error

> Expected to stub methods on object but found none

Which comes from the line where I create the stub instance

```
const serviceStub = sinon.createStubInstance(Service)
```

Why is it complaining about no methods on the object (`Service`) when I have several? The test run crashes on that line, doesn't get in to any of the testing code so I have omitted that.

Sinon version: 11.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP stated in his answer, sinon seems to have problems with arrow type functions exposed in classes. For me it happened with async functions.

```js
export Class A {
  public get = async () => {
    {...}
  }
}
```

The solution was indeed to change from arrow style to normal named functions:

```js
export Class A {
  public async get () {
    {...}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some `console.log`s in the sinon package, I saw that the methods weren't being exposed. The answer was to change the class methods which were using arrow functions.